# How to count and categorize pixels in a jpeg using VBA in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to use excel to analyze pictures for number of pixels in images, instead of buying a software package for it. I have three ranges on the RGB spectrum that I will use to categorize each pixel. I want my program to read each pixel and see what category it falls into and output this into a cell or a msg box. I am just unfamiliar with the syntax behind this as the algorithm is fairly simple and just requires a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I tried something like that. I look right now at the code, and really don't understand it properly, and have no time to reduce it to their essentials. Anyway, it might help you to get started. Paste the following code, paste an image in that sheet, and assign the macro Picture1_Click to the image. Then click on the image, and you'll get RGB of that point.

```
Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINT) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

    Dim C As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim la As Integer


Private Type POINT
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
Sub Picture1_Click()

    Dim pLocation As POINT
    Dim lColour, lDC As Long
    la = la + 1
    lDC = GetWindowDC(0)
    Call GetCursorPos(pLocation)
    Rprom = 0
    For i = -5 To 5
    For j = -5 To 5
    lColour = GetPixel(lDC, pLocation.x + i, pLocation.y + j)

    C = lColour
    R = C Mod 256
    G = C \ 256 Mod 256
    B = C \ 65536 Mod 256
    Rprom = Rprom + R
    Next j
    Next i
    Rprom = Rprom / 121
    getRGB2 = "R=" & R & ", G=" & G & ", B=" & B
    Range("a" & la + 1).Value = la
    Range("b" & la + 1).Value = R
    Range("c" & la + 1).Value = G
    Range("d" & la + 1).Value = B
    Range("e" & la + 1).Value = Rprom
    Range("f" & la + 1).Value = pLocation.x
    Range("g" & la + 1).Value = pLocation.y
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, pLocation.x, pLocation.y, 10, 10). _
        Select
    'ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 20, 20, 10, 10). _
        Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 10
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0.5
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 10
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    Selection.Characters.Text = la
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Normal"
        .Size = 6
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0#
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginRight = 0#
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginTop = 0#
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0#

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey this is great, unfortunately I need every pixel and not just ones that I click on because I need the color breakdown of the whole image. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: I can't analize the code right know, but it seems that you're getting cursor position (`GetCursorPos`) and the get the color of that position (`pLocation.x, pLocation.y`). I think you should skip that code, and make a loop that scan all the image, recording and averaging pixels colors.